# EntityManagerFactory spring boot too slow

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm having a problem with spring boot and hibernate.
To initialize is taking too long as you can see in the log (+20 minutes).
How can I have more information from log to know what the spring/hibernate is doing between those two steps?

Thank you

```
2020-03-23 15:27:16.199  INFO 6268 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-23 15:27:16.223  INFO 6268 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2020-03-23 16:06:19.187  INFO 6268 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Until now not solved.

Comment: It should not take so much time. try to set root log level to debug.

Comment: You may want to look at your db connection settings, are there any hosts you are connecting to that may be timing out?  In the past I've seen this with replicated setups where one of the servers was unreachable.   Try simplifying and connecting to a know working host.

Comment: This just happens when I'm working connected by VPN working at home. Looks like a network problem. I need to have more information to make a better analysis. How can I set root log level to debug? application.yml? level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    com.howtodoinjava: DEBUG
    org.hibernate: DEBUG